# Attenuation - two stage RC low‐pass filter

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, filter, low-pass

I am having trouble with finding the **attenuation** and **bode diagrams** for this circuit below.

[image: voltage follower]

This circuit is two stage RC low-pass filters. I have been trying to find resources on how to do them with operational amplifiers (it is my first time using them). Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your circuit shows two cascaded \$RC\$ filters. You can determine the transfer function of this simple circuit using the fast analytical circuits techniques or FACTs. Simply reduce the excitation (the input voltage) to 0 V and "look" through the connecting terminals of a capacitor (which is temporarily disconnected) to determine the resistance \$R\$ you see. That resistance multiplied by the capacitance forms the individual time constant \$\tau\$ you need. The below sketch shows how to do this:

[image]

Once you have determined the time constants, you can assemble them in the way I have described in the [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1119236371) I wrote on the subject. The below Mathcad sheet shows the final result:

[image]

The op-amp is wired as a voltage follower and shields the filter from the load you will connect on the output. Its presence does not affect the transfer function if we consider a perfect element.